# How to increase icon size in a QTableWidgetItem in Python Code

Tags: python, pyqt6

I load .ui file within my main.py.  The .ui file contains a QMainWindow with a QTableWidget displaying 6 rows of data with 4 columns.

The last column for each row contains an image (icon) within a QTableWidgetItem.  The image is determined by a function call passing the `work_type`, status to `get_image(work_type, status)`.

The icon for the last cell is set by the following, looping through a record set:

```
image_path = self.get_image(rec[4], rec[6])

actual_img = QIcon(image_path)

row_img = QTableWidgetItem()
row_img.setIcon(actual_img)

schedule_grid.setItem(row, 3 row_img)
```

The `row_img` is determined and assigned properly but no where can I find the `setIconSize()` method to set the proper size for `row_img` so the images are defaulting to a tiny size.

Comment: Item views always follow the [`iconSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#iconSize-prop) set as default for the view. If you only show icons in that column and all icons will have the same reference size (it's resized keeping aspect ratio), just set that property; otherwise you can use `row_img.setData(Qt.DecorationRole, QPixmap(image_path))`, but if you want proper scaling and per-item sizing, you need a custom delegate.

Comment: I'm using PYQT6 on Ubuntu (Linux) and the QTableWidgetItem does not have a setIconSize method.  Only exists for the Table and sets icon size for all cells.  I did manually resized the images to fill the cell and achieved what I was initially wanted.

Comment: I know that QTableWidgetItem doesn't have a `setIconSize()`: as I specifically wrote in my comment, that is a function of *item views*, which is what the property linked above refers to.